# PHP add column and entry to a array in while loop

Tags: php, mysql, json, mysqli

I making a web socket book search app and I want to add a column with entries to the `MySQL` query received. I will also do a `json_encode` to `entryData`. The query is like this.

```
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT Title, Author, ISBN, Publisher, Year
                             FROM books
                                 WHERE Title = '$title' OR Author= '$author'
                                 OR isbn='$isbn' OR Year='$year' ");

$entryData = array();
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
{
   $entryData[] = $row;
   $entryData->category = $category;
}
```

Something is going completely wrong in my `while loop`, however when I add the data from the `MySQL` query manually to the `entryData` array it works. So I must be doing something wrong in the query.

Comment: So you want to add category to each row, right?

Comment: @RajdeepPaul yes, category column will have the same values or entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ...all category column will have the same values or entries.

So your `while` loop should be like this:

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
    $row['category'] = $category;
    $entryData[] = $row;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Sir, I could have sworn I did what you have.

Comment: @Jam1 Glad I could help. *Cheers!* :-)